# Java units of measurement libraries other than JSR-275 and Units of Measure API

Tags: units-of-measurement, jsr-275

Are there any Java libraries dealing with units of measurement except for [JSR 275](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=275) (rejected and abandoned) and Units of Measure API (which doesn't seem to have any production-quality implementations)?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? JScience seems full featured but with very little activity, seems like there would be a great need for this kind of library so it's surprising.

Comment: @RasmusStorjohann No, I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [units](https://github.com/uhoefel/units) library that does not use static typesetting (as in many practical applications I encountered this would have been more cumbersome that I would like such a library to be).
It is designed to handle string based units as well as sharper defined units.
Some of the supported features include:

- conversions of values, e.g.:

  ```java
  Units.convert(3, "m", "mm");
  Units.convert(3, SiBaseUnit.METER, "mm");
  ```

  would both return `3000`.
- simplification of string based units, e.g.:

  ```java
  Units.simplify("kg^3 m^4 s^-6 A^-1");
  ```

  would return `"J^2 T"`.
- finding the names of a unit in a specific context, e.g.:

  ```java
  Units.inContext("lx s", UnitContextMatch.COMPATIBLE, PhysicsContext.PHOTOMETRY)
  ```

  would return a navigable set containing `("luminous exposure")`.
- supports [SI units](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/), binary units, [imperial units](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1985/72), [US customary units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units), [atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units), [planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) and many more. The user can also easily define own units.
- fully supports arbitrary logarithmic units, e.g.

  ```java
  LevelUnit.BEL.inReferenceTo(1, Unit.of("mV")); // automatically determines ref type -> root power
  LevelUnit.BEL.inReferenceTo(1, Unit.of("W"), LevelUnitReferenceType.POWER); // specify type explicitly
  Unit.of("ln(re 1 nA)") == LevelUnit.NEPER.inReferenceTo(1, Unit.of("nA")); // true
  ```
- supports SI prefixes, binary prefixes and allows the user to easily implement own prefixes
- Can handle unknown units if not relevant, e.g.:

  ```java
  Units.convert(3, "m^2 this_is_not_a_unit", "mm^2 this_is_not_a_unit");
  ```

  would return `3e6`, as the unknown unit `this_is_not_a_unit` is the same on both sides of the conversion.
- for performance critical parts of the code one can obtain the conversion factor (if the conversion is purely multiplicative), e.g.:

  ```java
  Units.factor("kg", "t");
  ```

  will return `1e-3`.
- Allows to check for equivalence, e.g.

  ```java
  Units.equivalent(1, "s", "min");
  ```

  will return false, as `1min` is not the same as `1s`. On the other hand, checking for convertibility

  ```java
  Units.convertible("s", "min");
  ```

  will return `true`.
- tightly integrated in the [coordinates](https://github.com/uhoefel/coordinates) library (as of Java 16 this library still requires preview-features, but as of Java 17 it will production ready)

The constants are implemented via a `Constant` interface that supports e.g.:

- definition of own constants, e.g.

  ```java
  // (3 ± 0.2) mole
  Constant.of(3, 0.2, "mole");
  ```
- chaining commands, e.g.

  ```java
  // constant with the distance travelled by light in vacuum in (2 ± 0) seconds as value
  PhysicsConstant.SPEED_OF_LIGHT_IN_VACUUM.mul(2, 0, SiBaseUnit.SECOND);

  // constant of the elementary charge per (electron) mass
  PhysicsConstant.ELEMENTARY_CHARGE.div(PhysicsConstant.ELECTRON_MASS);

  Constant c = Constant.of(3, 0.2, "mole");
  PhysicsConstant.SHIELDING_DIFFERENCE_OF_T_AND_P_IN_HT.mul(c);
  ```
- (simple) uncertainty propagation
- the `Constant` interface provides default implementations for the `Texable` interface from the [jatex](https://github.com/uhoefel/jatex) module, such that a constant can easily return proper LaTeX code.
- properly documented implementations for most of the physics constants as defined by NIST, as well as some mathematical constants.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an opensource [Unitility](https://github.com/pjazdzyk/unitility) for working with physical quantities and units of measurements including easy conversion between them. Example of usage:

```java
// Creating temperature instance of specified units
Temperature temperature = Temperature.ofCelsius(20.5);         // {20.50 °C}

// Getting converted value for calculations
double valueInCelsius = temperature.getInCelsius();            // 20.50 °C
double valueInFahrenheits = temperature.getInFahrenheits();    // 68.90 °F

// Checking property current unit, value, and value in base unit
TemperatureUnits unit = temperature.getUnit();                // CELSIUS
TemperatureUnits baseUnit = unit.getBaseUnit();               // KELVIN 

// Changing property unit and converting back to base unit
Temperature tempInFahrenheits = temperature.toUnit(TemperatureUnits.FAHRENHEIT);
Temperature tempInKelvins = temperature.toBaseUnit();
```

Additionally, logical and basic math operations are supported within quantities of the same type:

```java
// Logic operation example:
Temperature smallerTemp = Temperature.ofCelsius(-20.0);             
Temperature greaterTemp = Temperature.ofCelsius(0.0);   
smallerTemp.isLowerThan(greaterTemp);                              
greaterTemp.isGreaterThan(smallerTemp);  

// Math operation example:
Temperature sourceTemperature = Temperature.ofCelsius(20);
Temperature temperatureToAdd = Temperature.ofKelvins(293.15);
Temperature actualTemperature = sourceTemperature.add(temperatureToAdd); // {40°C}
```

Maybe this will be helpful if you are looking for something simple. It supports a selection of most typical physical quantities and its units for SI and IMPERIAL units.
If you need any specific unit or quantity to be added - just let me know.

Edit: 2024.01.16

- it now includes modules for Spring and Quarkus support to preconfigure object mappers for easier use in web applications
- maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.synerset/unitility-core

Comment: Nice library! This is much more elegant than JSR-363.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se from JSR 363

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/0.6.2-RC1

Hopefully your problem got solved approx. 4 yrs ago!

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.